# $X$ is completely regular iff it carries the initial topology w.r.t. $C(X,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: general-topology

I've read that

> A topological space $X$ is completely regular iff it carries the
>   initial (weak) topology w.r.t. $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ where $C(X, \mathbb{R})$ is
>   the set of all bounded real-valued **continuous** functions $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

(Don't we need a topology on $X$ before we can talk about continuous functions on it?)

I'm having trouble understanding this statement because, as I understand things:

The initial topology induced by **any** family of functions $f_i: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the smallest topology which makes each $f_i$ continuous. So the initial topology induced by $C(X, \mathbb{R})$ must just be the one we started with. Then any space must be completely regular, so what is there to define?

Comment: Here's a reference: [Infinite Dimensional Analysis: A Hitchhiker's Guide, pg. 50](https://books.google.com/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=completely+regular+topology+C(x,R)&source=bl&ots=parNSwd0Nz&sig=VzL70sBJPIgMWmkkfzEKmQFRfB0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMmZiv-P3LAhWFbhQKHS0CBU4Q6AEIUDAH#v=onepage&q=completely%20regular%20topology%20C(x%2CR)&f=false)

Comment: Thanks! It's a bit more subtle than I thought.

Comment: I'd still really appreciate an example of a space that's not completely regular (i.e. carries a larger topology than $\sigma(X,C)$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do need a topology on $X$ and indeed, $X$ is by the assumption a topological space.

What the statement means is that $X$ is completely regular if and only if the original topology on $X$ *coincides* with the initial topology with respect to $C_b(X,{\bf R})$ (which is, in general, coarser).

For examples of Hausdorff spaces which are not completely regular, you may want to consult the [$\pi$-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=T_2%2B%7ECompletely%20regular). There is also a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/698324/30222) here on math.se.