# Is the Mysior Space paracompact?

Tags: general-topology, plane-geometry, separation-axioms, paracompactness

I want to find out if the space defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/698429/116321) is paracompact. I think it is not but I'm not able to prove it. I tried applying the fact that a Lindelöf T3 Space is Paracompact but this space isn't Lindelöf since the open cover containing only one $U_n$ would need a subcover to have uncountably many open nbds of the form $V_x \setminus A$ to cover the $x$ axis elements. I also tried proving it [fully normal](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fully_Normal_Space_is_Paracompact). I also tried applying this: "A regular space is paracompact if every open cover admits a locally finite refinement. (Here, the refinement is not required to be open.)"

I think for an open cover with a single $U_n$, any open nbd of $x(x\leq n)$ of the form $V_x\setminus A$ or $U_m$ has to intersect infinitely many members of the refinement otherwise it would contradict the fact that each $V_y\setminus A$ has only finitely many holes. Kindly provide hints.

Comment: Paracompact Hausdorff spaces are normal, hence completely regular.

Comment: @which gives us a contradiction, thanks!. Do you think proving this straight from the definition of Para compactness is also trivial?

Comment: You could try to adapt the proof that paracompactness implies normality to this space. But then you still have to show that the space is not normal.